# Query the size of a Laravel queue

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I am planning to use Laravel Queue, and now I am doing some research:

Is it possible to get the size of a Laravel queue? Even better, can I get some statistics of a Laravel queue?

Comment: What queue driver you want? Author of Laravel gave you [Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/horizon) do you need anything else?

Comment: I am open for any good solutions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
Queue::size($queue);
```

The [size method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Queue/Queue.php#L7) will return the size of the given queue. `Queue::size()` will return the size of the default queue.

If you are using redis you can use [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/horizon) to get more detailed insights into what is happening in your queues.

Comment: In case you have a different connection you can use the `connection()` function e.g. `Queue::connection($connection)->size($queue);`